# Filtering third-party Python warnings with newlines

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, warnings

I am trying to suppress a warning from a third-party module (in this case, PyTables via Pandas) using an environment variable.  The warning starts with a newline.

Example of warning:

```
python -c 'import pandas as pd; pd.DataFrame([None]).to_hdf("test.h5", "/data")'
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:2606: PerformanceWarning: 
your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot
map directly to c-types [inferred_type->mixed,key->block0_values] [items->Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')]

  pytables.to_hdf(
```

According to the Python documentation I can specify a warning to ignore by setting `PYTHONWARNINGS` in the format `action:message:category:module:line`

##### Using `category`

I tried `PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore::PerformanceWarning`, however this gives me the message `Invalid -W option ignored: unknown warning category: 'PerformanceWarning'`.

`PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore::pytables.PerformanceWarning` gives me `Invalid -W option ignored: invalid module name: 'pytables'`.

##### Using `message`

I initially tried `PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore:your performance may suffer` which does nothing, likely due to the warning message starting with a newline.

Further exploring the newline case, I tried to insert a newline, however it is either escaped or removed:

```
PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore:\nyour performance" python -c "import warnings as w; [print(f) for f in w.filters]"
('ignore', re.compile('\\\\nyour\\ performance', re.IGNORECASE), <class 'Warning'>, None, 0)
// ...
```

```
PYTHONWARNINGS="$(echo -n "ignore:\nyour performance")" python -c "import warnings as w; [print(f) for f in w.filters]"
('ignore', re.compile('your\\ performance', re.IGNORECASE), <class 'Warning'>, None, 0)
// ...
```

```
PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore:.your performance" python -c "import warnings as w; [print(f) for f in w.filters]"
('ignore', re.compile('\\.your\\ performance', re.IGNORECASE), <class 'Warning'>, None, 0)
// ...
```

How can I disable this warning?

(I am aware that I can do it using something like `python -c 'import pandas as pd; import warnings as w; w.filterwarnings("ignore", "\nyour performance"); pd.DataFrame([None]).to_hdf("test.h5", "/data")'`, however it is quite inconvenient for my use case.  I could also solve the underlying issue, but that is not a small task)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem occurs because `PerformanceWarning` isn't a built-in warning category ([list here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html)).

Based on your use case you can use an approach below, but be careful as some heavy-handed approaches may also suppress useful warnings.

If you want to ignore all warnings when running a script from the command line you can use:

```
python -W ignore myscript.py
```

Your example:

```
python -W ignore -c 'import pandas as pd; pd.DataFrame([None]).to_hdf("test.h5", "/data")'
```

Inside of a script you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings

# Create your own warning filter
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=pd.errors.PerformanceWarning)
```

Your example:

```
python -c 'import warnings; import pandas as pd; warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=pd.errors.PerformanceWarning); pd.DataFrame([None]).to_hdf("test.h5", "/data")'
```

I would recommend using some variation of the second approach where you explicitly ignore the specific warning(s) you don't want to see.

Comment: In my case it is tricky to do it using warnings filters from Python as I have some cases where multiple scripts are running in several different processes and it would be a lot of work to modify them all.  Ignoring all warnings is definitely an option, but I would like to avoid suppressing useful warnings.